# mod_rewrite help to change Content-disposition based on URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory of mp3 files want to have be able to serve them inline or giving the user an option to download based on the request URI.

/media/file1.mp3  -- in this case, I just want to serve the file and let the browser play it.

/media/download/file1.mp3 -- in this case, I want to make it easy for a user to download the file instead.

I have been able to accomplish this with mod_rewrite and php (using the header() and readfile() function) but I would rather do it all with mod_rewrite, mod_header etc if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With mod_rewrite you can only change some specific header fields but to which the *Content-Disposition* header field doesn’t belong. You could only change the *Content-Type* header field:

```
RewriteRule ^media/[^/]+\.mp3$ - [L,T=audio/mpeg]
RewriteRule ^media/download/[^/]+$ - [L,T=application/octet-stream]
```

And if you want to use a [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html)+[mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) solution:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/media/download/ force-download

<IfDefine force-download>
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had been trying this unsuccessfully:

SetEnvIF Request_URI "^/media/download" force-download=1
Header set Content-Disposition attachment env=force-download

Answer (score 5):

*IfDefine* will check variables set on start-up of Apache so that won't work. A valid config would be:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/media/download/ force-download
Header set Content-Disposition attachment env=force-download
```

Also changing the Content-Type is not necessary to force a download.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to base rule on parameters in URI, here is the logic / syntaxe (adapt RewriteCond) :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dl=1$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,E=FORCEDOWNLOAD:1]
Header set Content-Disposition attachment env=FORCEDOWNLOAD
```

Here, we force download if the only parameter is "dl=1"